TF2 Best Practices for large transforms trees
I've been using ROS2 for a while now, but mostly in projects which don't involve large transform stacks. Recently I've started a project involving drilling holes in many locations ~100+ with multiple mobile robots (with their own transforms).
I am not familiar with the internal workings of tf2_ros and I was wondering what the best practice is for managing a potentially large transform tree and whether:

Every Hole can and should have a transform?
Every Hole could have a transform but its probably not a great idea to be hauling such a large transform tree around?
Group the holes and have a single transform per group, with internal transforms to the rest of the holes in the group managed by the user

I'm mostly concerned that having to constantly update and looking up within a large tf tree over wifi with multiple mobile robots feels to me like to it could be quite significant for bandwidth and performance.
I would appreciate it if somebody could enlighten me one way or the other
Thanks guys!

I think it would be good to visualize how you currently have it structured (even if approximated with a napkin sketch for simplicity). At this scale and traversing the tree with some transform bottlenecks over a wireless connection, its worth thinking about what transforms need to be where to reduce crossing bottle necks as much as possible -- and thinking if some things strictly need to be connected at all.
